Calculate hours using a start time and end time column
How can you get the hours to display in a decimal for example someone work 8:15 to 4:30 and I want it to display 7.25 hours?
I used this formula but I cant get minutes displayed as above:
=IF(ISBLANK([Column2]),"0",TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h"))


Use formula like this:
=IF(ISBLANK(EndDT),0,(INT((EndDT-StartDT)*1440))/60)

Output:

